# How to repeat the array elements with specific sequence according to some number?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, linq, math

If I have this array of integers :

```
int[] columns_index = { 2, 3, 4};
```

How can i repeat this sequence according to given number (size)?

---

For example :

if i give u `4` as a size then the array will be

**{2,3,4,2}**

if i give u `5` as a size then the array will be

**{2,3,4,2,3}**

if i give u `6` as a size then the array will be

**{2,3,4,2,3,4}**

if i give u `7` as a size then the array will be

**{2,3,4,2,3,4,2}**

And so on ...

Comment: this looks like homework, is it?

Comment: :) no ..................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the modulo operator to iterate through the `columns_index`

```
int input = 7; // change this to user input of whatever it needs to be
int[] numbers = new int[ input ];

for ( int i = 0; i < input; i++ ){
    int index = i % ( columns_index.length )
    numbers[i] = columns_index[ index ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T[] Multiply<T>(this T[] array, int length)
    {
        if ( array == null || array.Length == 0 || length <= array.Length )
            return array;
        var x = length % array.Length;
        var y = length / array.Length;      
        return Enumerable.Range(1,y)
               .SelectMany(c=>array)               
               .Concat(array.Take(x))
               .ToArray();                          
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1+ Same idea as mine. Your answer is just so much more elegant. Mine is as basic as it gets. I'll leave it up, in case someone can use it and don't understand yours.

Comment: Sorry, working now.  Unfortunately I can't remove the down vote unless you make an edit.

Answer (score 2):

One can use the Linq `Repeat()` and `Take()` functions to get the result.

```
private readonly static int[] Source = { 2, 3, 4 };

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1() {

    Assert.IsTrue(new []{ 2, 3, 4, 2}.SequenceEqual(GetSequence(Source,4)));
    Assert.IsTrue(new[] { 2, 3, 4, 2, 3  }.SequenceEqual(GetSequence(Source, 5)));
    Assert.IsTrue(new[] { 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4 }.SequenceEqual(GetSequence(Source, 6)));
    Assert.IsTrue(new[] { 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2 }.SequenceEqual(GetSequence(Source, 7)));

}


private static int[] GetSequence(IEnumerable<int> src, int count) {
    var srcRepeatCount = count / src.Count() + 1;
    return Enumerable.Repeat(src, srcRepeatCount).SelectMany(itm => itm).Take(count).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you preferred to seperate the part where you use all in columns_index with the rest

```
        int input = 1000001;
        int[] columns_index = { 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] numbers = new int[input];

        // Times we can use everything in columns_index
        int times = input/columns_index.Length; // 333333
        List<int> numbersList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        {
            numbersList.AddRange(columns_index);
        }
        // numbersInt.Count is now 999999..

        // Times for the rest
        int modTimes = input%(columns_index.Length); // 2
        for (int j = 0; j < modTimes; j++)
        {
            numbersList.Add(columns_index[j]);
        }

        numbers = numbersList.ToArray();
```